# Java Generics lowerbound

Tags: java, generics

Could anyone please let me know why this doesn't work?

```
List<? super Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Object());
```

My understanding is that the variable list can hold any value as long as it is a superclass of Person. Object is definitely a superclass of Person, then why it can't be added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a class hierarchy as `Object -> Movable -> Person` and in that case `List<? super Person>` can point to:

1. list of `Movable` ( `List<Movable>`) or
2. list of `Object` (`List<Object>`)

You do not know what type of elements (`Movable` or `Object`) list will have exactly at run time (generics is compile time phenomenon).

That is the reason insertion is not allowed in such case because it might end up adding `Object` to list of `Movable` at runtime. So golden rule is `Producer Extends Consumer Super`.